# observer gets default value when subscribed

Tags: rxjs

I have a Subject that is happily emitting values to subscribes.

I wonder, is it possible to get default value when you subscribe to the observable? Observable is fixed in this case, and observers are getting added on the fly. But when added, it should receive default value.

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject("default"); //sth like this
subject.onNext("first value");

var newSubscriberHere = subject.subscribe(function(val){
  console.log(val);  // should print the default value.
});
```

Comment: `Behavior Subject` just like Subject, but with default value: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md

Comment: If you already called .onNext("future value"), all the fiture subscribers will receive "future value" when subscribed. Isn't that the case? They should still receive "default value" as the first value they get,

Comment: The observable class has an option startWith(). unfortunatey it returns Observable. Because I want to be able to call .onNext() method, I need to convert observable returned from startWith() into  Subject (observer).